# Get sum of numbers within range (from 0 to user input)

Tags: ruby, sum

This is the code i am using, its purpose is for the user to enter an integer, the program will then take the sum of all the numbers up to and including the one entered. There is probable an easier way to do this

```
 sum = 0
 puts "please enter a number"
 counter = gets.chomp.to_i
 begin
  sum += counter
  counter -= 1
 end while counter == 0
```

Comment: you loop will only execute once (or twice if the input is 1) since in most cases the counter will be different from 0

Comment: Like @RuneFS said, the issue with your code is at `end while counter == 0`, if you changed that to `end while counter != 0`, it would do what you want it to.

Answer (score 1):

The issue with your code is in `counter == 0` condition in your loop, since it runs only once and then if `count` is not equal to `0` (in other words, if user's input wasn't `1`), it stops. You not only can make this without using loops, you can shorten the whole process:

```ruby
counter = gets.to_i
sum = (0..counter).inject(:+)
```

[**Demo**](http://repl.it/mgZ/3)

*P.S. As you could have noticed, you can omit `.chomp` when you are using `.to_i`.*

Answer (score 0):

Yes, use something like this (`sum` from ActiveSupport):

```
sum = (counter + 1).times.sum
```

or without ActiveSupport:

```
sum = (counter + 1).times.inject(&:+)
```

Comment: since the counter is decremented in each iteration that will not give the same result

Answer (score 0):

```
num = gets.to_i
sum = num*(num+1)/2
```

Comment: I totally missed this is the basic pure maths solution to the sum of a summation series! thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly, you could try something like this...

```
puts "Please enter a positive number..."
number = gets.chomp.to_i

puts "Sum of all numbers is: #{ (1..number).inject { |sum, n| sum + n} }"
```

I'm using enumerable method 'inject' to sum up the total. Learn more about 'inject' method at http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Enumerable.html#method-i-inject.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

As I understand you are trying to sum elements of range. Giving number 3, you want to get sum which is 6.

One way (time consuming) is to use `inject` or `sum`. You can try following:

```
1. [*1..value].sum
2. [*1..value].inject(:+)
```

The other (recommended), very efficient way is to use this equation:

```
(value + 1) * (value) / 2
```